# How do I fix error when connecting two if else statements?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new at java and creating my first project which is a calculator using intellij. I have created two if else statements the first one takes the average given by the user and turns it into a grade. The second one is supposed to take the grade then turn it into a gpa. i have declared String grade; and String gpa.

```
  if (avg >= 90.0 ) {
    grade = "A";
  } else if (avg >=80.0) {
    grade = "B";
  } else if (avg >=70.0){
    grade = "C";
  } else if (avg >=60.0) {
    grade = "D";
  } else {
    grade = "F";
  }
  System.out.println("Grade is  " + grade );
  if (grade = A ) {      
    gpa = "4.0";        
  } else if (grade = B) { 
    gpa = "3.0";        
  }
```

Edit: The grade equals solution fixes the first error with the red underline but it doesn't compile. So I ended up using a switch statement instead in order to get two print statements.

Comment: The issue is the A next to grade = is highlighted red and I am not sure how to fix. Also the same thing happens for B.

Comment: You seem to try to check for the string "A" but are missing the quotation marks.
Also you have an assignment in the if-condition and not a comparison. Probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @user10455554 when i add quotation marks it underlines the entire line (grade = "A") in red

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: A single equals sign is the assignment operator. If you just want your code to compile, you need to change it to a double equals, like `if (grade == "A")`. But if you want your code to actually be *correct* you need to compare strings using the equals() method: `if (grade.equals("A"))` (see the possible duplicate question)

Comment: Try `if (grade.equals("A"))` (and same at the else if) 
See the linked question posted by user dnault

Comment: @dnault it got rid of the red underline from the A but it doesn't let me display the gpa with System.out.println(" gpa is " + gpa "); there is a red underline in gpa now and i can't check if it complies

Answer (score 1):

```
if (avg >= 90.0 ) {
   grade = "A";
} else if (avg >=80.0) {
   grade = "B";
} else if (avg >=70.0) {
   grade = "C";
} else if (avg >=60.0) {
   grade = "D";
} else {
   grade = "F";
}
System.out.println("Grade is  " + grade );
if (grade.equals("A")) {      
   gpa = "4.0";        
} else if (grade.equals("B")) { 
   gpa = "3.0";        
}
```

Comment: That compiles, but is not [the correct way to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

```
if (grade = A )
```

to check if it's equal, you should use == (for comparing references) or `equals` for string.

`A` is not a variable, but a string you want to compare to, so it should be `"A"`

there's no really point in doing it in two separate if's. do it once:

```
if (avg >= 90.0 ) {
   grade = "A";
   gpa = "4.0";
} else if (avg >=80.0) {
   grade = "B";
   gpa = "3.5";
} else if (avg >=70.0){
...
...
```

Comment: The reason I made separate if else statements is because I wanted the program to print a separate line telling the user what their grade is and what their gpa is. I am not sure if it can work combined.

Comment: You can still have two prints at the end